# finding zero probability using characteristic functions

Tags: probability

I found this characteristic function:

$$

E[e^{-\lambda X}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda k} P(X=k)

$$

How can I find P(X=0)?

Comment: That looks like a moment-generating function.  You want $E[e^{-it X}]$ for a characteristic function.

Comment: Assume $X \geq 0$. By dominated convergence theorem, we have $$ \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \mathbb{E} [ e^{-\lambda X} ] = \mathbb{E} [ \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} e^{-\lambda X} ] = \mathbb{E} [ \chi_{\{X = 0\}} ] = P(X = 0). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry says, it's the moment generating function of $X$, and its value is taken at $-\lambda$. We can write 
$$E[e^{-\lambda X}]=P(X=0)+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda k}P(X=k),$$
and for $\lambda >0$
$$0\leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda k}P(X=k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda k}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$
so $\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}E[e^{-\lambda X}]=P(X=0)$ and if you know $E[e^{-\lambda X}]$ and its limit when $\lambda\to +\infty$ is not too hard to compute you can deduce $P(X=0)$.